# Event fired when clicking back on UserControl tab page

Tags: c#, winforms, events

The code below is from a `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` and works fine. It is included, along with other UserControls, on a tab page (itself a user control). The user can click off this tab page by clicking on another tab, doing some stuff, and then clicking back to this tab page. 'Doing some stuff' could include changing data that this control is displaying. However, when clicking back, the `OnLoad()` method of either this control or its parent is not called, and so `OnViewReady()` is not called and the control is not updated. What event would be used to capture clicking back to the original tab page?

```
protected override void OnLoad (System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this._presenter != null)
    {
        this._presenter.OnViewReady();
    }
    base.OnLoad (e);
}
```

[The docs for UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) shows no method `OnShown`.
`GotFocus`would require the user to click on the control in order to update it.

Comment: Looks like you are talking about your customized `TabControl`, there are too few info to answer this question, the person who understands this custom control best is you, no one can help, just suggestion or question back ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be to use `OnRefresh()`:

public override void Refresh()
{
    this.myBindingSource.ResetBindings (false);
    base.Refresh();
}

Answer (score 0):

The `OnLoad` event only occurs when the object is first created

> The Load event occurs after the control is created, but before the
>   control becomes visible for the first time.

Not when you change focus.  If you want to run something every time that the user selects a tab on the TabConrol you can use another event for it.  `TabIndexChanged` looks like your best option, `GotFocus` may be something to look at as well.

focus events occur in the following order:

- Enter
- GotFocus
- Leave
- Validating
- Validated
- LostFocus